Standard error clustering with few clusters
I am trying to estimate the causal effect of police presence on crime rates using county-level crime data from 166 counties across three states. The treatment is assigned at the state level. For my basic estimation (TWFE including county, year, month-of-year, and day-of-week), I cluster the standard errors at the county level. However, I am aware that the common approach is to cluster at the treatment level. Since this is not possible with only three clusters, an alternative would be to use wild cluster bootstrapped standard errors (Cameron et al., 2008). I am uncertain whether the WCB approach is viable with only three clusters.
Has anyone encountered a similar problem or could offer some advice?
Kind regards

It sounds like you have a sample of all 166 counties from 3 US states (out of a population of ~51 possible states and ~3,243 counties), with all counties in one state treated. This means there are at least two potential reasons for clustering:

a sampling reason, which arises because you have sampled data from a population using clustered sampling, and want to say something about that broader population
a design reason, where the assignment mechanism for the causal treatment of interest is clustered.

This implies that even if you just want to say something about the effect in treated counties (rather than the broader population), you need to cluster your SEs. Treatment effect heterogeneity across clusters can be a third reason.
The closest framework for this problem is

When Should You Adjust Standard Errors for Clustering?, Alberto
Abadie, Susan Athey, Guido W Imbens, Jeffrey M Wooldridge, The
Quarterly Journal of Economics, 138(1):1-35, 2023. https://doi.org/10.1093/qje/qjac038

There’s Stata code for the Causal Cluster Variance Estimator here. Unfortunately, it only allows for FEs, so you will have to modify your approach from TWFE.
The WCRBS may NOT work well: it always under-rejects very severely when there is only one treated cluster, and the problem tends to be most severe when the number of treated units is small (as is likely the case with only 166 counties). See section 5.3 in

MacKinnon, J.G., Webb, M.D. (2020). Clustering Methods for Statistical
Inference. In: Zimmermann, K.F. (eds) Handbook of Labor, Human
Resources and Population Economics. Springer, Cham.
https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-57365-6_43-1 (Ungated WP version)

The authors suggest that the ordinary (i.e., non-clustered) WBS may sometimes work better. There is a nice example of that reanalyzing Conley and Taber’s (2011) subanalysis of Georgia’s HOPE program (and comparing it to the full 10-treated-states analysis) in this paper:

Roodman, D., Nielsen, M. Ø., MacKinnon, J. G., & Webb, M. D. (2019).
Fast and wild: Bootstrap inference in Stata using boottest. The Stata
Journal, 19(1), 4-60. https://doi.org/10.1177/1536867X19830877

It includes some histogram diagnostics to detect failure: the bootstrap distribution will be bimodal.
There are a couple of other approaches that could serve as complements for robustness or as substitutes:

Donald, Stephen G., and Kevin Lang. “Inference with
Difference-in-Differences and Other Panel Data.” The Review of
Economics and Statistics 89, no. 2 (2007): 221–33.
http://www.jstor.org/stable/40043055.
Hagemann, A. (2023). Inference with a Single Treated Cluster. (Revise and resubmit at the Review of Economic Studies, 2nd round.)
https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.04076

The first requires homogeneous clusters. The second does not and has R and Stata code here. Hagemann also has a few other papers in this area that may be relevant using permutation inference.
Two other ideas to consider:

A synthetic cohort might be another option (instead or as a robustness check) if there are relatively few treated counties or if you can get more county-level or state-level data. However, this will only get you the ATET rather than ATE.
Get more states, especially treated ones if possible.


@Schwa97 Did this answer your question?
